# Why does ASP.NET Core Web API running under IIS still need EnableBuffering() to read a request body more than once even when using pipelines?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

For an authorization handler on an endpoint we need to pull a value out of the request body in order to determine if the user is authorized. This same body will need to be reread for the endpoint itself.

We are using a pipeline to extract the information as follows:

```
            var pipeReader = httpContext.Request.BodyReader;
            var result = await pipeReader.ReadAsync(httpContext.RequestAborted);
            var buffer = result.Buffer;

            // Indicate we haven't consumed anything so that the endpoint can read the request body as well 
            pipeReader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

            // Code that processes buffer to get what we want
```

This works perfectly fine when running under Kestrel (either in Visual Studio 2022 sandbox or directly).

However, when running under IIS, we have to enable buffering and reset the body position or we get a return status of 400 with the message "A non-empty request body is required."

```
            var request = httpContext.Request;
            request.EnableBuffering();
            var pipeReader = request.BodyReader;
            var result = await pipeReader.ReadAsync(httpContext.RequestAborted);
            var buffer = result.Buffer;

            // Indicate we haven't consumed anything so that the endpoint can read the request body as well 
            pipeReader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

            // Reset position to allow reread of request body
            request.Body.Position = 0;

            // Code that processes buffer to get what we want
```

So two questions:

1. Why? Why does this work fine under Kestrel but not when running IIS as a reverse proxy (IIS Express also suffers the same issue)?
2. Is there really any reason to use pipes in this case? Since pipes are supposed to be more efficient since they don't require additional buffering and are also in theory supposed to simplify code, am I really seeing any benefit here since I have to explicitly enable packet body buffering and need to add additional code to reset the request body pointer anyway?

Comment: You probably won't get an easy answer without debugging into ASP.NET Core module, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/v7.0.10/src/Servers/IIS I don't recall anywhere in IIS/ASP.NET Core documentation such details were provided. Besides, when ASP.NET Core in-process hosting is used (default now on IIS), IIS behaves more than just a reverse proxy, so when you described isn't a surprise either.  If you switch to out-of-process hosting, probably the issue is gone.

Comment: As far as I understand, Kestrel is more flexible and efficient than IIS in terms of reading and writing the request and response bodies, because it can do so asynchronously and incrementally, while IIS has to do so synchronously and completely. Kestrel supports response trailer headers, which are headers sent after the response body. IIS does not support response trailer headers, because it buffers the response body and sends it all at once. Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0.